# Count how many times a character changes in a string

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have this string as an input for an example:

```
string value = "fffeefef";
```

My problem is and I cant figure out how/what I should do. I want to count how many times in the string it changes from f to an e and vice versa which the output should be 4. The string might be changed so I cant figure out the algorithm. If you guys can enlighten me I would appreciate it! I know it sounds very easy, but im still learning. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: Added comments to explain every part, as requested.

```
string value = "fffeefef";    // Set some value to use in the example
int counter = 0;              // Initialize the counter, still zero changes found
for (int i = 1; i < value.Length; i++)    // Make a loop, iterating for every char in the string
{
    if (value[i - 1] != value[i])    // Compare every char with the previous char, starting at char 1 (the second char, as first position is zero).
        counter++;            // If the chars are different, increase our counter
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you explain the loop so I understand it better for future purposes?

Comment: I was starting to write an answer with a `foreach`. A simple `for` makes much more sense in this case.

Comment: @Pajala added explanations, as requested. Do not hesitate to request more details, if you need it.

Comment: Thanks alot @BlasSoriano . It solved my problem which I´ve been stuck with for hours! Im still learning and I appreciate that you guys dont look down on us beginners!

Comment: @Pajala, you can read more about `for` loops [from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx). A string is just an array of chars so he is using array notation on it to compare the chars.

Answer (score 6):

See example:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/9vvlNw

```
    string stringValue = "fffeefef";

    int characterChanges = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < stringValue.Length; i++) 
    {
        if(stringValue[i] != stringValue[i - 1])
        {
            characterChanges++;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Character changed {0} times.", characterChanges);
```

A string is just an array of characters, so you can access them via index. We create a simple for loop that iterates `n - 1` number of times (because we start at 1), where `n` is the length of the `stringValue` (`stringValue.Length`). Our if statements says if the current character is not equal to the character before it, increment a counter (`characterChanges`).

The first iteration of the for loop would read: is character at index 2 equal to the character at index 1, then is character 3 equal to character 2, and so on...

Comment: Thanks alot! It really helps. But could you answer me how the if statement see when the character changes? If you could describe it abit... (I know, im new and i am trying to learn!)

Comment: Added a bit of an explanation for you.